# Oil change done wrong

Tags: oil-change, oil-leak, gmc, terrain

So I recently took my 2011 GMC Terrain to get an oil change. My truck takes synthetic oil so oil changes are pretty pricey!  It’s only been about 2 1/2 weeks since I gotten this oil change and since than I haven’t drove anywhere far just work and home, maybe a store here and there.  Being it’s thanksgiving I decided to go outta town ( a 1hr and 35min drive). My truck was driving just fine got on the expressway and came to some bad traffic! My truck started to stall and ended up cutting off. I tried to start it up and it seemed to not want to start but once it did I noticed that it sounded funny a noise I never heard it make. The noise and the fact that it kept stalling I had to get off the expressway and pull over. My brother in-law was in the car with me and checked my oil. Bone dry!! How could this be! I just got an oil change not even a month ago!! I was across the street from an autozone thankfully and went to get oil.  That didn’t seem to help a Machanic was called and he noticed that my oil was all in my undercarriage! And my engine is knocking. The Machanic also stated that my engine rods are ruined due to the fact all my oil leaked out. Is it possible that the people who did my oil change didn’t put my oil filter in the right way? I park in the same spots at work and home I didn’t see any oil stains or spots on the ground. I Was told I should contact the last people who touched my car which was the people who did my oil change. When I spoke to the man he told me that just because I got my oil changed by them doesn’t mean my oil would leak out!! I don’t kno much about cars but I only had this truck since May and had one other oil change prior to this one and nothing like this happened before. Also I do know that I didn’t have no oil leak because if that was the case I would of seen oil stains where I park at

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If it was not leaking in the 2 1/2 weeks since the oil change as you point out with no evidence, it may not be their fault and could be down to something else, possibly... But how often do you check the oil level? Once per week? Before long trips?

Comment: Did you not receive a low oil level or pressure warning?

Comment: I do normally check my oil levels but seeing as how I just got the oil change I didn’t think to check it any time soon. I have a feature that shows me my oil life and normally when it gets to about 80 or 75% I check my oil levels. Since I just got the oil change and haven’t driven any long distance my oil life is still at 96% I believe. My truck doesn’t let me know when the oil pressure is down it only shows the oil life

Comment: 2011 GMC Terrain should have a low oil pressure warning light that will illuminate if the pressure drops below the setpoint. It is a graphic representation (picture) of an oil can with a drip of oil coming from the spout. You can ensure the warning light is functional by checking to see if it illuminates when you first turn the key on. It should illuminate briefly then turn off, to show you that the light bulb is functional.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that the people who did my oil change didn’t put my oil filter in the right way?

Yes, but without proof you will have a very difficult time getting the "oil changer(s)" to do anything about it. You did not mention in your post whether or not the mechanic that was called found the oil filter loose or missing; this could be an important clue that might lead back to the "oil changer(s)" having some responsibility.

Have a reputable professional mechanic determine the cause of the loss of oil, and if it is related to a loose or missing filter you could have her put it in writing and confront the "oil changer(s)" with a demand for repair. They will likely deny responsibility which means you take legal action, buy a new motor, or buy a new truck... your choice.

Comment: Yes I plan on having a certified car repair shop take a look at my truck and tell me why it is that I lost oil if it is because of a lose oil filter or plug I will be reaching out to the people who done my oil change

Answer (score 1):

Because the vehicle had not left drips of oil where you park it, it would look like it was not a slow leak from a bad oil change.  I would guess that a component has failed, such as your engine oil cooler or one of the pipes that connect to it.

It is possible that the sump plug or oil filter wasn't tightened enough at the oil change and that because this is the first time that the engine has reached full temperature for a long period that one of them has come loose.  It should be very obvious by looking at the engine if this is the case.

Comment: I haven’t looked to see if The oil filter is loose or the plug since it was late in the day Wednesday and thanksgiving being the next day everything was closed (car repair shops) I’m going to get the truck towed to a repair shop a certified one at that and have them inspect it for me and tell me why is it that I lost all my oil

Comment: That is the only way of finding out what has really happened.